# What does 'd stand for?

Tags: word-meaning

I'm wondering what the 'd stand for? (had, did, would, could or should?)

Please tell me the things that can be used as the abbreviation 'd.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on context

In

> I'd gone to the store before my friend came.

it stands for *had*. "I had gone to the store..."

In

> I'd have done a better job.

it stands for *would*. "I would have done a better job."

In

> What'd he do?

it stands for *did*. "What did he do?"
Note: in many cases, *did* must be emphasized and you can't abbreviate it in those cases.

I can't think of any examples where it can be used for *should*, or *could*, mainly because any of these examples might have *would* as an alternative, so the meaning would be ambiguous.

Comment: Some authorities (at least) hold that **'d** can stand for *should* ( https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/I'd ), but it only ever does so in cases where it could equally well stand for *would* (and where it has the same meaning), and indeed there are many speakers who would never the word "should" as a synonym for "would" - a usage which isn't found (afaik) in AmE and is probably a minority usage in BrE.

Comment: @rjpond, I believe it. *Should* is also used differently in BrE from AmE, so that could have an effect too.

Answer (score 0):

*'d* is normally either had or would - depends on context:

*I'd tell you* : I would tell you

*I'd told you* : I had told you

*I'd like to tell you* : I would like to tell you

*I'd better stop* : I had better stop

There are others as @charles pointed out, but not used as much as the above

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66724/discussion-between-charles-and-mplungjan).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest checking out [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:List_of_English_contractions) list of English contractions, and to look for those which end with *'d*. To list a few, and their expanded form(s):

- I'd -- I *had* : I *would*
- He'd -- he *had* : he *would*
- How'd -- How *did* : how *would*
- That'd -- that *would* : that *had*

There are 16 of these in total.